# Intro.js start counting steps from the first step, skipping the first (introcution) one

Tags: javascript, angular, intro.js

In my Intro.js user adoption tutorial I need to show steps number starting only from the second step (the first one is only an introduction step without an element reference). So in that case the counter shuould be 1/n for the "second" step, then 2/n and so on.

How can I change the numeration and the visibility of the steps counter according to my needs?

Example that reproduce my problem:

```
this.introJS.setOptions({
  nextLabel: 'Next',
  prevLabel: 'Prev',
  showStepNumbers: true,
  stepNumbersOfLabel: '/', 
  steps: [
    {
      title: 'MyTitleIntro',
      intro: 'MyIntrod description, without steps progress counter'
    },
    {
      element: '#step1',
      title: 'First Step',
      intro: 'Should be 1/2'
    },
    {
      element: '#step2',
      title: 'Second Step',
      intro: 'Should be 2/2'
    }
]});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `showStepNumbers` and `stepNumbersOfLabel` options, along with a custom function to calculate the step numbers.

```
this.introJS.setOptions({
  nextLabel: 'Next',
  prevLabel: 'Prev',
  showStepNumbers: true,
  stepNumbersOfLabel: '/',
  steps: [
    {
      title: 'MyTitleIntro',
      intro: 'MyIntrod description, without steps progress counter'
    },
    {
      element: '#step1',
      title: 'First Step',
      intro: 'Should be 1/2'
    },
    {
      element: '#step2',
      title: 'Second Step',
      intro: 'Should be 2/2'
    }
  ],
  // Define a function to calculate the custom step numbers
  // The function takes the current step index and the total number of steps as arguments
  // and returns a string in the format "x/n", where x is the custom step number
  // for the second step onwards
  getStepNumber: function(stepIndex, stepsCount) {
    // Calculate the custom step number, starting from 1
    var customStepNumber = stepIndex;
    if (stepIndex > 1) {
      customStepNumber--;
    }
    // Return the custom step number and the total number of steps as a string
    return customStepNumber.toString() + '/' + stepsCount.toString();
  }
});
```